# Where can I find the lastest EF7 change documentation?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have updated my .net5 ef7 project to rc-1 but it has broken quite a bit of my project I believe I upgraded from .7, I cannot seem to find very much documentation on the changes made in particular to EF7. For example

```
  using ComicEndpoints.Repository;
  using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
  using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
  using Newtonsoft.Json;


        services.AddOptions().AddEntityFramework()
                .AddDbContext<DB_56875_Context>();
```

no longer seems to work and I cannot find an alternative. Maybe I am missing some package but I cannot figure out which one. My Project.json dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.1-beta2",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
},
```

Comment: Which part of it is giving an error? Have you tried to google that particular error and see if anyone else is having it with EF7? The latest change log and bug fixes for RC1 is on https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases

Comment: are you getting build errors or runtime errors, I think you need to provide error detail to get a specific concrete answer. I know a lot of the mssql specific entitytypebuilder extensions were renamed. What does your DB_56875_Context code look like? I noticed today that they have updated [the docs](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in the last day or so. There is a lot of new content there that was not there a few days ago.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddEntityFramework' and no extension method 'AddEntityFramework' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: No beta8 stuff should remain, use EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer package from RC1

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET 5 RC1 Release notes on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases) and the ASP.NET [Announcements repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements) is about as good as it gets.

As for specific APIs that changed, there are no specific notes. This is still pre-release so docs have been light and we haven't produced change notes.

That said, EF7 documentation is now hosted at [docs.efproject.net](http://docs.efproject.net)